# How should I update Xcode if I have previously downloaded it from the Apple website?

Tags: applications, time-machine, xcode, software-update, mac-appstore

I just upgraded from an Intel-based MacBook to a newer Apple Silicon-based MacBook and migrated everything using Time Machine. In doing so, this moved my old Xcode installation to my new Silicon machine. I am not sure if there are any issues I need to be aware of in this case when transitioning to the newer Silicon architecture.

I must've downloaded Xcode from the Apple website back in the day because the App Store shows Xcode is not installed. How should I go about updating this? I don't want to leave unused files on my machine from updating and sure don't want two separate installations of Xcode. Would it be better to remove my entire Xcode installation and install from the App Store (and if so how?) or is there an update script or something similar to update my current installation?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I'd recommend that you delete the current Xcode app and reinstall it from the App Store (there may be some "update script" that I don't know of or the App Store might notice that Xcode is already installed, but you will have to download the newest Xcode version anyway as Apple released an update a couple of days ago...).